# Wrong plotting in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

When running the below code, it displays a wrong plot.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

st=dt(2016,3,1)
end=dt(2016,3,10)
df=data.DataReader(name="GOOG",data_source="yahoo",start=st,end=end)
p=figure(x_axis_type="datetime",height=300,width=1000)
p.title.text="CandleStick graph"
p.rect(df.index[df.Close > df.Open],(df.Close+df.Open)/2,12*60*60*1000,abs(df.Close-df.Open))
show(p)
```

Comment: How is it wrong? What is it showing vs what you were expecting?

Answer (score 2):

All the data columns need to be the same length, but you are passing one that is shorter than the others:

```
df.index[df.Close > df.Open]
```

Actually running your code, Bokeh even tells you exactly this:

```
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. 
Current lengths: ('height', 9), ('x', 5), ('y', 9)
```

You are only passing 5 coordinates for `x` and 9 coordinates for all the others. The arguments all need to match up. You can either:

- Not do the subsetting on `df.index` at all
- Subset all the other arguments in the same way

*(For future reference: you should **always** include any error or warning messages such as the one above in your SO questions—and, as @sjc mentioned, describe the problem in actual detail, not just state "is wrong")*